# how to create TCP socket between UWP app on Windows 10 and Xamarin.Forms app on iOS device

Tags: c#, ios, sockets, xamarin, uwp

I want to stream live camera frames from my Windows 10 computer to my iPad, which will display the frames, in real time.

I want to develop on Windows 10 using Visual Studio for both the Windows 10 app and the iOS app.

I'm considering Windows Universal > Blank App project for the Windows 10 computer app,
and iPhone & iPad > IOS XAML APP (XAMARIN.FORMS) for the IOS app.

Which TCP socket technology should I use for the Windows UWP app, and which for the IOS XAML app?

Answer (score 0):

For the iOS application, I'd use [libvlcsharp](https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp) which is cross-platform .NET/Mono bindings for libVLC. It should be quite simple to setup for receiving a video stream from the UWP application.

Then on the UWP side, Microsoft provides a good example of capturing and streaming video using the Media Capture API in the [Real-time communication sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleCommunication) on GitHub.

I know that this doesn't directly answer your question about creating the TCP socket but should anyway point you to the right direction. It's been a while since I looked into developing a similar solution myself.